# Typescript how to filter data created date and expiration date

Tags: typescript, datetime

how can I filter the product whose current date is within the created date and the current date does not exceed the expiration date?

```
async getAllproduct():Promise<Array<Product>>{
   const currentDate = new Date(Date.now() - 86400 * 7000);
   const product: Array<Product> = await this.findProductStatus(
      currentDate,
      ProductStatus.active
   );
   const activeProduct = product.filter((product) => product.CreatedDate > currentDate && product.ProductEndAt < currentDate);
   return activeProduct;
}
```

I don't know if the logic <`product.CreatedDate > currentDate && product.ProductEndAt < currentDate`> here is right, please correct me on this, I just want to filter the product that has the current date (Date.now) is within the `createdDate` and does not exceed the expiration date

Comment: Does your code not work? What type are the `CreatedDate` and `ProductEndAt` properties?

Comment: i dont received any error , but it doesnt work that i expect, the properties of `CreatedDate` and `ProductEndAt` is `Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic should use

- `date > CreatedDate` - date is *after* the created date
- `date < ProductEndAt` - date is *before* the expiration date

```ts
async getAllproduct(): Promise<Array<Product>> {
   const lastWeek = new Date()
   lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() - 7)

   const products: Array<Product> = await this.findProductStatus(
      lastWeek,
      ProductStatus.active
   );

   return products.filter(({ CreatedDate, ProductEndAt }) =>
     lastWeek > CreatedDate && lastWeek < ProductEndAt)
}
```

Comment: Hello, I get this error `Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Date' and 'number'.`

Comment: @kaito I've changed my answer to only use `Date` instances but it seems you missed my note about using `.valueOf()`

Comment: maybe because of this `new Date(Date.now() - 86400 * 7000);`

Comment: @kaito that does not appear in my answer or in your question

Comment: @kaito I've update my answer to match your new requirements

Comment: the result of my `CurrentDate` is like this `2022-02-25T02:33:19.701Z`